# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow - Help Desk System

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have created the following custom list;

- CreatedBy
- ModifiedBy
- AssignedTo
- Description
- Priority
- Attachments
- Status
- Completed (Yes/No)

I have created a work flow that basically Sends and email notification to the helpdesk team and copies the creator once job is logged. However, I need some more process that I wish for it to be captured in the work flow which I am having difficulty considering my lack of 'know how' being a newbie.

I need a workflow that will;

1. Send email to Helpdesk and copy Creator that request has been submitted
2. Then send an email to the creator when Helpdesk changes the status to 'work in progress' or Resolved.
3. If the creator modify's/appends the Description, I want another email sent to helpdesk and copy creator of the change.
4. Once the helpdesk has sorted the issue and input their comments (appended in the description), and set the completed to 'Yes' email is sent to the creator with the comments and the creator cannot edit again.

Thanking you in advance for any assistance.

Regards

Teine

Comment: If you are not having any fixed format/template for sending emails...then OOTB alerts will be good choice to notify the help desk group and creator.

Comment: Thank you @GaneshSanap. As a newbie, I'd like to do it in Designer so I can learn to automate other processes.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can create simply Helpdesk [video 1 here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jXnKU9Ntn4), [video 2 here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoZmQF8Dk74).

Here are some posts about working with workflows:

- [Introduction to designing and customizing workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b)
- [Simply HD workflow](https://blogs.perficient.com/2011/07/01/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-help-desk/)
- [Creating HD](http://sforsharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/08/helpdesk-ticketing-system-in-sharepoint.html)
- [Creating a Help Desk in SharePoint](http://abhayajoshi.blogspot.com/2011/07/creating-help-desk-in-sharepoint-2010.html) **recommending this** but look on all posts

*Hope it helps!*